# vim: removing multiple lines - d3d vs 3dd

Tags: vim

I was speaking with my friend about removing multiple lines while using **vim**. They said they use **d3d** to remove 3 lines, whereas I use **3dd**

I understand my command is: 3 (repeat 3x) dd (delete the entire line)

And my friend's command is of the form **["x]d{motion}** i.e. Delete text that {motion} moves over [into register x].

However, I don't think **3d** is a valid motion. Is it?

I don't understand why this **d3d** command works in vim

Comment: In case you didn't know, there's a dedicated section of Stack Exchange for Vim: [vi.se].

Comment: Ah. I did not. But I did find my answer there. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up asking this same question on Vi Stack Exchange and got an informative answer. You can follow it here:
[Page on VI stack Exchange answering this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/31428/removing-multiple-lines-d3d-vs-3dd)

The relevant part is the TLDR:

> tl;dr [count]d is not (a) valid (Motion) in Normal mode, but it is valid in Operator-pending mode when the current Operator is d.